# How to get all the html elements found by document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript

In the DevTools, I want to print or copy to the clipboard all the elements of a certain class name. I am interested in the HTML code itself, not in JS objects/code. I tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("some_class_name")      //returns some kind of object
document.getElementsByClassName("some_class_name")[0]  //gives HTML but only of the first found element, rather than all found elements.
```

I ultimately want to do something like:

```
copy(document.getElementsByClassName("some_class_name"));    //place found elements in the clipboard
```

So that I can paste it in my code editor to further understand it.

Edit1:

The end result I am expecting is for my clipboard to have the following:

```
<div class="red_car">car1</div>
<div class="red_car">car2</div>
<div class="red_car">car3</div>
<div class="red_car">car4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the contents of the elements as strings with `.innerHTML`, concatenate them, and put this in the clipboard.

Since `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, you have to loop over it to get all their contents.

```
// concatenate all the contents
let contents = [...document.getElementsByClassName("some_class_name")].map(el => el.innerHTML).join("\n");
copy(contents); // place in clipboard
```

Comment: Hey while this works as you intended, its not what I am after. I am interested in the HTML tags and their content. I should have shared an example of what I expected, pardon me. I have updated my OP.

Comment: Then use `.innerHTML` to get the HTML tags.